# If the URL contains "default.aspx" on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to get .aspx links to open in a new window, but not if the hyperlink end in `'/default.aspx'`

this works..

```
$("a[href$='.aspx']").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
```

but I need it to detect if the page contains `'default.aspx'` and **NOT** run the scipt.

This kind of works..

```
if ("a[href$='default.aspx']" != -1) {
    $("a[href$='.aspx']").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @BrettZamir I'd say that it should be `$(...).length > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) :

```
$("a[href$='.aspx']:not(a[href$='default.aspx'])").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

See the attribute contains selector in the api documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/.

In short, this will add `target="_blank"` to any link that doesn't contain "default.aspx" and also remove the link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='.aspx']").not("[href*='default.aspx']").removeAttr('onclick')
                                                       .attr('target', '_blank');
});
```